# Android Multipart file upload with access token

Tags: java, android, file-upload, multipart, android-file

I want to send access token as a multipart data along with the file to the php server. I wrote the following code but it is giving 401 Unauthorized error. I think I am not passing the access_token. How to do it?

```
public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

    TextView messageText;
    TLConstants tlConstants;

    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    final String uploadFileName = "service_lifecycle.png";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        tlConstants=new TLConstants();

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- '/mnt/sdcard/"+uploadFileName+"'");

        /************* Php script path ****************/

        upLoadServerUri = tlConstants.getURL(tlConstants.uploadFile);

        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
                            }
                        });

                        uploadFile(uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                    +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                            +uploadFilePath + "" + uploadFileName);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        }
        else
        {
            try {

                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                HashMap<String, String> databaseMap = databaseHandler.getUserLoginAuthDetails();

                // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);


                String access_token= databaseMap.get("accesstoken");
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

                dos.write( ("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + "access_token" + "\"\r\n").getBytes());
                dos.write( ("\r\n" + access_token + "\r\n").getBytes());



                // create a buffer of  maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();


                Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                if(serverResponseCode == 200){

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    +"../media/uploads/"
                                    +uploadFileName;

                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "File Upload Complete.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                //close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "MalformedURLException",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on server configuration. In general, if you need to pass a authorization token with your Http POST, its passed with the header with `setHeader`. Here's my working code snippet for multi-part file upload.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
File file = new File(selectedImagePath);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);

post.setHeader("token", myAuthToken);
post.setHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE,
                    Constants.BOUNDARY, Charset.defaultCharset());

entity.addPart(Constants.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_NAME, new FileBody(file));
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

post.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
Log.d("Response", EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
```

Comment: Thanks Reaz for the help. Can you tell me please that how to read the response here? Will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see the edited answer. If the answer is helpful please accept and upvote it.

Comment: I tried your code and read the response too. The server is saying that it is not receiving the access_token param.

Here is the response from the server:

{
 "error": "invalid_request",
 "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."
}

I changed this line in your code:

post.setHeader("access_token", myAuthToken);

Comment: Looks like the token should be passed as a parameter not in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Working copy of Multipart image upload using service:

```
private MutipartImageUploadModel handleUploadAction(int tileId) {
        String imageName = getTilesInUploadPath(this, fileId);
        if (imageName == null) {
            return null;
        }
        InputStream responseInputStream;
        try {
            File filesDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
            File imageFile = new File(filesDir, imageName);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            double bytes = imageFile.length();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(ServiceConstantInterface.URL_UPLOAD_IMAGE);            httpPost.setHeader(ServiceConstantInterface.Authorization_KEY, ServiceConstantInterface.Authorization_KEY_VALUE);
            httpPost.setHeader("SessionKey", new SharedPrefDataSupplier(this).getmSessionKey());
            MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            entityBuilder.addPart("file_name", new FileBody(imageFile));
            entityBuilder.addPart("file_id", new StringBody(String.valueOf(fileId)));
            entityBuilder.addPart("SessionKey", new StringBody(new SharedPrefDataSupplier(getApplicationContext()).getmSessionKey()));
            HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                responseInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                if (responseInputStream != null) {
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(responseInputStream);
                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    MutipartImageUploadModel wResponse = gson.fromJson(reader, MutipartImageUploadModel.class);
                    Log.i(TAG, "Response " + wResponse);
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                        responseInputStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return wResponse;
                }
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Server responded with status code: " + statusLine.getStatusCode());
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to send some headers, access tokens, cookies then you should set it in the request properties part like:

```
// Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("file", fileName);
            **conn.setRequestProperty("COOKIE_NAME_OR_TOKEN", mToken);**
```